# Drop down list come with scroll bar in chrome

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu

In chrome some cases drop down list items come with scroll bar,I want to display all items without scroll bar when drop down click,In my case all items are available in drop down list,but only one showing and need to scroll to see others.

Code given below.

```
<div class="controls">
                            <select name="teamId" id="teamIdSel" class="span2" >
                                 <?php foreach ($team_list as $team): ?>
                                    <option class="teamSelOpt" diviID="<?php echo $team->division_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $team->team_id; ?>" <?php if ($team->team_id == $teamId) { ?> selected <?php } ?> ><?php echo $team->name; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>    
                            </select>
                        </div>

<input type="button" onclick="onChangeDivision('10', null, null)"/>
```

Here I am dynamically displaying and hiding options using "diviID" in javascript.

javascript function given below.

```
 function onChangeDivision(id, teamId, clientUserID){
    if(id){
        $('.teamSelOpt').each(function() {
            var diviId = $(this).attr("diviID");
            if(diviId == id){
                $(this).show();
            }else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
}
}
```

When I remove "$(this).hide();" code from function it will work fine.But result will against my requirement.

Comment: So you want to change the standard, normal behavior of SELECT that everybody have known for years? Are you sure?

Comment: Make your own using JavaScript.

Comment: Dont use w3schools... they are misleading/wrong/incomplete/liars/ etc.. bad resource . Best to stick yo mdn or msdn

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a list instead and display it onhover/onclick just as Google does in Google plus. You cannot hide the scrollbar of a drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Normally these select,file upload etc are browser,os specific so we cant style them as we wish.
to achive consistency over all browsers for select boxes there are two methods

**Method1 :-**

you can create your own popup type thing using divs or ul & li and position it absolutly at required place and display it on click of the box.

**Method 2 :-**

you can simply use jquery plugin [dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) by which you can style select boxes as you wish and they will look same on all browsers